# How can Selenium Java to wait for AngularJS v 1.6

Tags: java, angularjs, selenium, automated-tests

I know there are several threads with this topic but none of the solutions i've found have worked for AngularJS v1.6

So here is what i've tried:

```
public void waitForAngularRequestsToFinish() {
    while ((boolean) jsExec.executeScript(
            "return (typeof angular !== 'undefined')? true : false;")) {
        jsExec.executeAsyncScript(
                        "var callback = arguments[arguments.length - 1];"
                                + "angular.element(document.body).injector().get('$browser').notifyWhenNoOutstandingRequests(callback);");
    }
}
```

This just gets stuck in an endless loop.

```
private void waitForAngularLoad() {
    String angularReadyScript = "return angular.element(document).injector().get('$http').pendingRequests.length === 0";
    angularLoads(angularReadyScript);
}

public void waitUntilAngularReady() {
    try {
        Boolean angularUnDefined = (Boolean) jsExec.executeScript("return window.angular === undefined");
        if (!angularUnDefined) {
            Boolean angularInjectorUnDefined = (Boolean) jsExec.executeScript("return angular.element(document).injector() === undefined");
            if (!angularInjectorUnDefined) {
                poll(20);

                waitForAngularLoad();

                poll(20);
            }
        }
    } catch (WebDriverException ignored) {
    }
}
```

this does nothing.

and i'm really stuck on this one. nothing seems to work, so any help is really appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Add JSWaiter utility class into your project.
Then, send WebDriver object to JSWaiter Class in a convenient place in your project by adding this line: “JSWaiter.setDriver(driver);”
Finally, you can use any of the methods below in your test code:
JSWaiter.waitJQueryAngular(); –> Both waits JQuery, Angular, JS

More details you can find at https://www.swtestacademy.com/selenium-wait-javascript-angular-ajax/

Comment: What you linked is already part of my question. I stole the waitUntilAngularReady from that exact site :D